# How fast does water have to be moving for it to gain a lot of heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, friction, water

A random question popped into my head a few minutes ago: objects, when moving fast enough, start to get resistance from the air. Since there is friction between the air and the object [water], there has to be some energy being added to the water. How fast would the water have to be travelling in order for the amount of friction to be so great the water would get significantly hotter (almost boiling)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After what speed air friction starts to heat up an object?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43768/)

Comment: Short answer: [Aerodynamic heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerodynamic_heating) only happens to objects moving near/above the speed of sound